# Contextual Action Bar text selection

Tags: android

is there any way to add a custom contextual action bar when text is selected like this:

[image]

I have had a look around like here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#context-menu

But it really doesn't have much information an the EditText selection.

I am using a physical Android 4.0.3 device so all the API is available to me.

Anyone have any ideas?

---

Edit for anyone who wants to know how to do this I documented the code here

http://www.muktware.com/4022/text-selection-cab

Comment: Site moved to muktware :D check the edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made my own version of this editing the code a bit to meet my needs, I do not believe that there is any actual way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Try [setting a custom `ActionMode.Callback`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback%28android.view.ActionMode.Callback%29) on your EditText. You've got control over the default actions, as well as the ability to add new ones.