# Override methods in contextual action bar

Tags: android, contextual-action-bar

When selecting text in an android text view, a contextual action bar comes up with options to copy, cut, select all, share, etc. Is there a way to capture the onClicks of these options and override them?

Comment: Not exactly. You can create your own ActionView, but you can't hijack clicks of others.

Comment: What about removing options in the menu, is that possible?

Comment: did you find an answer_

Comment: @noone Don't think I ever did.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating your own custom [ActionMode.Callback](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback%28android.view.ActionMode.Callback%29) for the text view. In the ActionMode.Callback you can create your own menu in which you can remove/change the options. You can also control the behavior with a

```
@Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {}
```

method override. see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#CAB and [Contextual Action Bar text selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10650984/contextual-action-bar-text-selection) for more information. Hope this helps!

Comment: I made a custom text-selection toolbar where I added the functionality for the user to be able to make a selected text bold/italic/underline etc. but after the customization, the default functions copy/paste/cut dont work anymore, but the icons for them still appears? How can theese be activated again?

Comment: When you debug it does it do anything when those buttons are pressed?

Comment: No nothing is shown, the only "default" button that works is the back-arrow. Here is how my custom contexual bar looks like: [LINK](http://i.imgur.com/OWBXApy.jpg)

Comment: I'm not sure what is happening but it seems like the view is including the default buttons but when you override the onActionItemClicked it is removing the actions that are supposed to happen when these default buttons are clicked. I would try explicitly trying to override the buttons action and just see what happens. If that works a non elegant solution would be to rewrite the default actions

Comment: I have tried that, with the copy function and it worked as it should.I found the code for the copy action and just pasted in my code for `case:android.R.id.copy`